# When will Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade the kernel version?

Tags: kernel, updates, thunderbolt

I'm having an issue related to lacking support for thunderbolt lane bonding which I reckon is fixed in kernel 5.5, is there any way of knowing when that'll be available in 20.04?
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.5-Thunderbolt-Changes

If possible I'd like to not have to mess around with installing mainline kernel version and going outside to regular update process

Comment: The first HWE kernel will ship with Ubuntu 20.04.2, currently no date for that is available (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) but it'll occur after 20.10's release as it'll be 19.10's kernel that gets used.

Comment: Many kernel improvement get backported to older kernels and show up in Ubuntu unepectedly. Look in Launchpad.net for a bug report on the issue, and subscribe to see the progress of the fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first HWE kernel will ship with Ubuntu 20.04.2, currently no date for that is available (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) but it'll occur after 20.10's release as it'll be 19.10's kernel that gets used.

Ubuntu 20.10 is scheduled to be released 22-October-2020 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) so it'll be after that.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to find a solution instead of waiting for a release to fix it

Comment: It looks like the release date is now 2021-02-04.

Answer (score 3):

It is very unlikely that Ubuntu will ever have the 5.5 kernel version.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 will have a new HWE kernel, but it will be released in a few months, closer to the year end.

**Update:** Ubuntu 20.04.2 will have the 5.8 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

> The 20.04.2 and newer point releases will ship with an updated kernel
> and X stack by default for the desktop. Server installations will
> default to the GA kernel and provide the enablement kernel as
> optional.

The point release 20.04.2 is currently [**scheduled for release on February 11th 2021**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule).

For people who do not wish to wait until then, it is possible to **install the HWE stack manually** before this date. On the date of writing this (Jan 7th 2021), **Kernel 5.8** [is available in the HWE stack](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic-hwe-20.04). As [mentioned in the first link above](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), it can be installed in the following ways:

On desktop systems:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04
```

On server systems:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party maybe, but until there's a HWE kernel newer than 5.5, you could install one from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

I'm using 5.8.x atm, as I have a relatively new AMD Ryzen 4000U chip, that's better supported with the newer kernel.

Comment: This would be my answer too.